# iphone ansi c : pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: iphone, c, pointers, memory, structure

I am using a c lib in my iPhone application. The c lib is written by someone I do not have access to.

However I am getting the error that object 0xa6000d is being freed but not allocated. The debug variable screenshot is here.

[image]

struct GtsMsg is defined as,

```
struct msg {
    int offset;
    int dataLength;
    u8* data;
    cBool expandable;
    cBool owned;
    u8* mid2key;
};

#define GtsMsg struct msg


void freeMessageData(GtsMsg* msg) {
    if (msg == NULL) return;
    if (msg->owned) {
        if (msg->data != NULL) {
            free(msg->data);
        }
    }
    free(msg->mid2key);
    memset(msg, 0, sizeof(GtsMsg));
}
```

The breakpoint for malloc_error_break is the line **free(msg->data).**

I have added the checking if (msg->data != NULL), but it did not work. What are the ways to check if the memory for msg->data or for msg is allocated or not?

Do you think there is something fishy, at *data = (u8)'\0'?

thanks in advance!

Comment: When you allocate the structure, do you set its pointer members valid values (pointers to allocated memory or NULL)?

Comment: That also I thought. The structure is used in some objective c and cpp class. Not explicitly initialized. But it works for all the cases. I am only getting in one special case, when the app is crashing.

Comment: That'll be your problem.  The pointer members must be initialised.  You can do this (1) by zero-filling memory on allocatation by using calloc, (2) by manually setting the pointers to point to allocated memory, (3) by manually setting the pointers to NULL.  Any code that works without one of these, is only working by chance and is prone to break in future

Comment: The check for `NULL` is useless as `free()` will be a no-op if the pointer passed to it is `NULL`. Just because a pointer is not `NULL` does not mean it points a valid memory location (the memory may have already been freed or the pointer was never initialized to `NULL`). It is the responsibility of the programmer to ensure that the pointer is valid before attempting to free it.

Comment: What can you tell us about the `owned` field of the struct? What does it mean? From the sounds of it, my guess is that you shouldn't delete `data` if `owned` is true, since usually "owned" means that something is owned (and therefore allocated/deallocated) by someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all to your suggestions. 
Thanks hmjd for your tips.

I found the struct is used in a cpp class which destructor calls the freeMessageData. But I could not find that the struct is initialized. So, if I initialize the struct to NULL in the declaration, this avoid the free memory problem and do not crash.

Its something suggested by simonc. If he writes that as an answer not, comment, I could accept that.

From comments of `hmjd`,

> The check for NULL is useless as free() will be a no-op if the pointer
>   passed to it is NULL. Just because a pointer is not NULL does not mean
>   it points a valid memory location (the memory may have already been
>   freed or the pointer was never initialized to NULL). It is the
>   responsibility of the programmer to ensure that the pointer is valid
>   before attempting to free it.